no operator ">" matches these operands. Genuinely confused
I'm completely new to C++. The problems I'm encountering is the following.

no operator ">" matches these operands


no operator "<" matches these operands


Answer = 19, answer is underlined with: Expression must have bool type(or be convertable to bool)

int main()
{
    cout << "What is 9 + 10?\n";
    
    cout << "Answer:";
    
    string Answer;

    cin >> Answer;

    if (Answer > 19)
    {
        cout << "Too high!";
    }
    
    if (Answer < 19)
    {
        cout << "Too low!";
    }
    
    if (Answer = 19)
        {
        cout << "CORRECT!";
    }
}

tried formatting a bunch of different ways but cant seem to get it to work.

What are cin and cout? Add the header or the modules, and depending on how do you do it, you may add std::cin and std::cout

You have Answer as a string.  19 is not a string, it's an integer literal of type int

Answer is a string.  How do you convert a string into a number in C++?  And what is the equality operator in C++?

Assuming that string is an alias of std::string, then it's a totally different kind of object to an integer.  What would it mean to compare "foo" with 19?

19 is an integer literal. Answer however is of type std::string and there is no comparison operator for those two. You can either change 19 to "19" (a string literal) or the type of Answer to int. And a single = is assignment and not comparison, which is ==. Additionally you want to check if reading from the standard input succeeded e.g. via if (!(std::cin >> Answer)) { handleError(); }.

C++ is a strongly typed language, so a string is not an integer. Time to do some basic C++ training first : https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/introduction-to-fundamental-data-types/

You should get yourself some good C++ books to learn from

@PepijnKramer too many languages today are loosey-goosey with this stuff.  Javascript comes to mind.

I'm completely new to C++.  What resource(s) are you learning C++ from?

It's also important that your code is a [mre].  The code you show here does not produce the errors you show here.

@MarkRansom I don't see where that remark comes from this is a C++ question. So OP deserves a C++ answer  :)  And C++ is not loosy goosy at all, you can even let the types system do a lot of checking for you. (e.g. you want a string representing an ip address, make a class for that (e.g. IpAdressString with string validation) and make function like void Connect(const& IpAddressString) and you can detect "illegal calls" with a std::string at compile time. So types are core to C++

@PepijnKramer I was just taking a wild guess on why they thought that would be acceptable syntax.  Totally agree on the benefits C++ brings to this.

I see :)  (I suspected python, or some other kind of scripting languge).  Note to OP, when you learn a new language : be prepared to forget everything you know (don't try to map concepts from one language to another). So really start from scratch :)

Answer need to be a numeric type like int instead of being a std::string. You can't compare a string value to an integer value, which is why you are getting errors on the < and > operators, as they don't exist for that combination of types.
Also, = is the assignment operator, which returns a reference to the variable being assigned to. An if needs a boolean expression but a std::string can't be implicitly converted to a boolean, which is why you get an error about that. You need to use == instead when comparing values for equality.
Try this:
int main()
{
    cout << "What is 9 + 10?\n";
    
    cout << "Answer:";
    
    int Answer; // <--

    cin >> Answer;

    if (Answer > 19)
    {
        cout << "Too high!";
    }
    
    if (Answer < 19)
    {
        cout << "Too low!";
    }
    
    if (Answer == 19) // <--
    {
        cout << "CORRECT!";
    }
}

That being said, you don't need the equality comparison at all if you use, if..else blocks instead, eg:
int main()
{
    cout << "What is 9 + 10?\n";
    
    cout << "Answer:";
    
    int Answer;

    cin >> Answer;

    if (Answer > 19)
    {
        cout << "Too high!";
    }
    
    else if (Answer < 19)
    {
        cout << "Too low!";
    }
    
    else
    {
        cout << "CORRECT!";
    }
}


I've been using Python too much, I thought a string could be implicitly converted to bool.

@MarkRansom Nope. A char* pointer is, but a std::string object is not.

@MarkRansom I think you mean implicitly converted to an int, the right side of the comparisons (19), not the result of the comparison?

@franji1 I was speaking about the result of an assignment, if (Answer = 19).  Since Answer is a string, the result will be a string as well and will need to convert to bool for the if.

It would be nice for the human if C++ did this, but I suspect that C++ does NOT do it because it would be hiding a potentially expensive transformation.
